# Write the definition of a class Player containing:

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

Write the definition of a class Player containing:

- An instance **variable**  name of type String, initialized to the empty String.
- An instance **variable**  score of type int, initialized to zero.
- A method called set_name that has one parameter, whose value it assigns to the instance **variable**  name.
- A method called set_score that has one parameter, whose value it assigns to the instance **variable**  score.
- A method called get_name that has no parameters and that returns the value of the instance **variable**  name.
- A method called get_score that has no parameters and that returns the value of the instance **variable**  score.

No constructor need be defined.

This is my code:

```
    class Player(object)
        name = ""
        score = 0
        def set_name(self):
            self.name = name
        def set_score (self):
            self.score = score
        def get_name
            return name     
        def  get_score
            return score
```

When I submit this, the only feedback My Programming Lab gives me is " You almost certainly should be using: , (comma)" and "compiler error(s)". I am not sure what to do with this information so any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advance

Comment: Get it to actually run and do what you want it to do before you submit it. This will tell you the errors you need to fix. Every method definition in your class contains at least one error.

Comment: your functions don't have any parameter for you to pass the score or name

Answer (score 0):

```
class Player(object): #notice the colon
    name = ""
    score = 0
    def set_name(self, name): #notice how it accepts (self, name)
        self.name = name
    def set_score (self, score): #notice how it accepts (self, score)
        self.score = score
    def get_name(self): #notice how it accepts (self) and has a colon
        return self.name #returns self.name not just name
    def get_score(self): #accepts (self) and has a colon
        return self.score #returns self.score not just score


thisPlayer = Player()
thisPlayer.set_name("greg")
print(thisPlayer.get_name())
```

Mostly just a bunch of syntax errors

Comment: Colon not semicolon!

Comment: No problem. If it answers your question then click the check to mark it as the answer so people know your question is resolved.

Comment: @Racialz: This solution is wrong. You define `name` and `score` as class attributes, not as instance attributes. You would need the `__init__` method to achieve what is asked.

Comment: @Matthias This works fine. The initial values are defined on the class, but any changed values are stored on the instance and override the class attributes. This is actually a nice way to provide default instance values when the values are immutable, since you don't need to store multiple references to 0 and an empty string.

Comment: @kindall: I'm not convinced. If I want instance attributes I don't use class attributes. If you adocate this usage of class attributes then you should be aware that someone will use this with mutable objects (e.g. lists) too, and that's the moment when the shit hits the fan.

Comment: Eh, we're all adults here. I don't necessarily *advocate* it but I do see it all the time,

Answer (score 0):

Corrections made below; each definition needs a colon at the end of the line, you didn't define the instance variables for the set methods, include self in the get method definitions, I always try not to use the same variable names for the instance variables

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name = ""
        self.__score = 0

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_score(self, score):
        self.__score = score

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_score(self):
        return self.__score
```